# Optimized Sieve of Eratosthenes in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, optimization, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm new to Haskell and for something I'm implementing I need a prime numbers list. I tried writing one, but it's too slow.

This is what I've tried doing.

```
primeList = primes 1000
primes :: Int -> [Bool]
primes x = primeRecursion 2 ([False,False] ++ replicate (x-1) True)
    where primeRecursion y l
            | y == x = l
            | not (l!!y) = primeRecursion (y+1) l
            | otherwise = primeRecursion (y+1) [ if (a>y && (a `mod` y == 0)) then False else l!!a | a <- [0..x]]
```

It works, but the algorithmic complexity is higher than the procedural equivalent, since for every prime number it goes through the whole list, not only its multiples. I can't find a way to make it O(n (log n) (log log n)), because of the way functional programming works. What is a (preferably simple and clear-looking) method of doing that?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sieve-of-eratosthenes+haskell ; https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers ; https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers_miscellaneous#A_Tale_of_Sieves ; http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Haskell ... https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers_miscellaneous#One-liners

Comment: Another article is https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf. It's not based around your article, but it's an interesting read nonetheless.

Comment: it was a very confusing read, for me, while the math parts were indeed enlightening.

Comment: An alternative approach that I used before was to pre-generate (or download) a large enough list of primes and then just load them within my program.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say you need this list of primes for something **else** you are doing, I guess you don't really need to implement it yourself, do you?  Have you looked at existing off-the-shelf solutions?

Several existing packages provide a `primes` function that gives the (infinite) list of primes:

```
primes :: [Integer]  -- or some other integral type
primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,...]
```

I looked at the versions in the [`primes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/primes-0.2.1.0/docs/Data-Numbers-Primes.html#v:primes), [`arithmoi`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.8.0.0/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Primes-Sieve.html#v:primes), and [`exact-combinatorics`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exact-combinatorics-0.2.0.8/docs/Math-Combinatorics-Exact-Primes.html#v:primes) packages.  The one in `arithmoi` seems blindingly fast.  The Stack script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-12.21 script --optimize
import Math.NumberTheory.Primes (primes)

main :: IO ()
main = print (sum $ take 1000000 primes)
```

uses `arithmoi-0.7.0.0` and sums the first ten million primes in about a second.

If you use the newer package version in `arithmoi-0.8.0.0` then `primes` has been redefined as a polymorphic list, so you'll want to define a monomorphic copy of the desired integer type:

```
primes' :: [Integer]
primes' = primes
```

and use that to avoid re-computing the list every time `primes` is used.  (See the documentation.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing at arithmoi. It does solve project Euler number 10 in 30 ms on my machine, a time I otherwise only have managed to reach by implementing the sieve of Eratosthenes in C++.